# Listview name cannot be read in C# file from a HubSection in XAML

Tags: c#, listview, datatemplate

I have a problem here, I have a universal app here (windows phone project) that contains a Hub and a HubSection, inside that HubSection I added a DataTemplate and a Listview with an Item template and data template for my binding.. here is the XAML Code

```
<HubSection  Header="games" x:Name="section2" Width="101" Height="625" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource HubSectionStyle1}" FontWeight="Thin" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,-63" >


                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      x:Name="listviewNews" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      ItemClick="listviewNews_ItemClick"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,-0.167,75.167">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"        
                                   Background="#FF15EDF7"

                                    Tapped="StackPanel_Tapped_1">
                                    <Image Name="MyImg"
                                   Source="{Binding ImageSrs}"
                                   Width="200" Height="300" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtb_Name"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                                       Foreground="Black"        
                                       FontSize="25" Margin="32,6,0,10.333" Width="182" Height="92"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>
```

The problem is when i try to build my project I get an error says : The name 'listviewNews' does not exist in the current context

putting in mind that 'listviewNews' is the name of my Listview and I guess that's what loads that listview.

Note: I have tried to run the same code out of the hub section (in a normal grid not in a hub) it worked fine.

```
MainPage.xaml.cs (where the error is located)

using Assembly_5_1_Program.Comon;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace Assembly_5_1_Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
        private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();
        ApplicationDataContainer _roamingData = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
        ApplicationDataContainer _localData = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

        ApplicationDataContainer _roamingNumberOfVisit = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
        ApplicationDataContainer _localNumberOfVisit = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

        /// <summary>
        /// This can be changed to a strongly typed view model.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
        {
            get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
        }

        // A pointer back to the main page.  This is needed if you want to call methods in MainPage such
        // as NotifyUser()
        MainPage rootPage = MainPage.Current;

        /// <summary>
        /// NavigationHelper is used on each page to aid in navigation and 
        /// process lifetime management
        /// </summary>
        public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
        {
            get { return this.navigationHelper; }
        }


        public static MainPage Current;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
            this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
            this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;
            //Which list to take data from?

            oFd.breakfast();    //list
        }
        FillData oFd = new FillData();



        /// <summary>
        /// Populates the page with content passed during navigation. Any saved state is also
        /// provided when recreating a page from a prior session.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">
        /// The source of the event; typically <see cref="NavigationHelper"/>
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that provides both the navigation parameter passed to
        /// <see cref="Frame.Navigate(Type, Object)"/> when this page was initially requested and
        /// a dictionary of state preserved by this page during an earlier
        /// session. The state will be null the first time a page is visited.</param>
        private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object navigationParameter, LoadStateEventArgs e)
        {
            listviewNews.ItemsSource = oFd.PublicList;
        }


        public static bool CheckInternetConnectivity()
        {
            var internetProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
            if (internetProfile == null)
                return false;

            return (internetProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess);
        }

        private bool ReadAppRatingSetting()
        {
            if (_localData.Values["AppRatingDone"] != null)
                return (bool)_localData.Values["AppRatingDone"];

            if (_roamingData.Values["AppRatingDone"] != null)
                return (bool)_roamingData.Values["AppRatingDone"];

            return false;
        }

        private void IgnoreRating(IUICommand command)
        {
            //SaveAppRatingSetting();
        }

        private async void OpenStoreRating(IUICommand command)
        {
            string name = Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;
            await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN=" + name));
            //await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN=6b7b722b-a69d-42fc-8fba-f1b30776edec"));
            //SaveAppRatingSetting();
        }
        private async void rate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!CheckInternetConnectivity())
                return;

            if (ReadAppRatingSetting())
                return;

            MessageDialog msg;
            bool retry = false;
            msg = new MessageDialog("هل يمكنك ان تساعدنا في تقييم التطبيق");
            msg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("قيم", new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.OpenStoreRating)));
            msg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("ليس الآن", (uiCommand) => { }));
            msg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("لا شكراً", new UICommandInvokedHandler(this.IgnoreRating)));
            msg.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
            msg.CancelCommandIndex = 1;
            await msg.ShowAsync();

            while (retry)
            {
                try { await msg.ShowAsync(); }
                catch { }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Preserves state associated with this page in case the application is suspended or the
        /// page is discarded from the navigation cache.  Values must conform to the serialization
        /// requirements of <see cref="SuspensionManager.SessionState"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event; typically <see cref="NavigationHelper"/></param>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that provides an empty dictionary to be populated with
        /// serializable state.</param>
        private void navigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public void listviewNews_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            int id = ((DataSource)e.ClickedItem).Id;
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(DetailsPageNews), id);
        }

        private void StackPanel_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        #region NavigationHelper registration

        /// The methods provided in this section are simply used to allow
        /// NavigationHelper to respond to the page's navigation methods.
        /// 
        /// Page specific logic should be placed in event handlers for the  
        /// <see cref="GridCS.Common.NavigationHelper.LoadState"/>
        /// and <see cref="GridCS.Common.NavigationHelper.SaveState"/>.
        /// The navigation parameter is available in the LoadState method 
        /// in addition to page state preserved during an earlier session.

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        }

        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(AppCategories));
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void grd_MyTiles_ItemClick_1(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error coming? Can  you please post that?

Comment: The error comes in this line:

listviewNews.ItemsSource = oFd.PublicList;

and exactly in 'listviewNews' it's underlined says the error I have mentioned